# How to set the creation date of a file in Mac OSX to the current date?

Tags: macos, date

I have tried to do this in terminal:

```
touch -t `date +%yy%mm%dd%HH%MM`/path/to/file
```

but it gives the error `touch: out of range or illegal time specification: [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]`. How can I get the right date currently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `date +%yy%mm%dd%HH%MM` by itself, and the problem should become apparent:

```
$ date +%yy%mm%dd%HH%MM
19y10m26d11H40M
```

The format code for a two-digit year is `%y`, so `%yy` gives a two-digit year followed by a stray "y". All the others work the same way. So just un-double all the format codes. Oh, and I recommend using `$( )` instead of backticks:

```
$ date +%y%m%d%H%M
1910261141
$ touch -t $(date +%y%m%d%H%M) /path/to/file
```

But it's actually easier than that, because `touch` defaults to the current time. So all you actually need is `touch /path/to/file`.